# Probability of three specific cards from different suits?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of chosing cards with numbers 3, 5 and 7 from different suits in a standart deck of 52 cards?

Comment: what's have you tried ?

Comment: @Yuri Adamov I assume this is without replacement.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are doing this without replacement. Let $S$ be the set of suits $[c,s,h,d]$ and let $s_1$ be the suit of the first card drawn. Since $s_1$ can by *any* of the four, then the probability for the first card is just the probability of getting a three, which is 
$$\frac{4}{52}$$
For the next card, let the suit be $s_2$. Then $s_2$ can be chosen from only three of the four suits - the three not yet chosen. Since it must also be a $5$, then the probability is 
$$\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{51}$$
For the last card, $s_3$ can only be chosen from $2$ of the $4$ suits, and it must be a $7$, so its probability is
$$\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{50}$$
Thus the probability of all $3$ happening is
$$\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{51}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{50}$$
I'll let you simplify that.